# When will I have the Gmail phone option in my Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-voice

I've read on the Gmail blog that the Gmail phone option hasn't been made available to everyone, however they will send out this facility to those who don't have it now later.

I'm a regular user of Google Voice and was thinking if usage of their Google Voice might be the reason they haven't given me the facility of Gmail phone yet on my Gmail. My browser are compatible, as required, to run Gmail phone.

Comment: Are you in the U.S.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this link: [google.com/chat/voice](http://www.google.com/chat/voice/) and if doesn't do the trick, then my guess would be that your Gmail's language is not set to English (US). If that's true then switch it to English (US) and check it again.

Comment: @Harpreet Happy free calling :)